# task displayName set to dynamic?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Is it possible to set the displayName of a ADO YAML task to be dynamic?

Use case:
I have a task to create an Octopus Release. However, the environment to create the release for is determined at run-time (based on source branch and others). I want to be able to have the displayName of the task to be something like this "Create Octopus Release for Development" or "Create Octopus Release for RC" etc. Using a variable does not work because it is resolved at run-time. Are there any solutions or workarounds?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your requirement, you can use the [If expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops) to set the display name  dynamically.

You can refer to the following two methods:

1. Based on my test, you can set using variable in displayname field. So you can  dynamically set the value of a variable using an expression.

   For example:

   ```yaml
   variables:
     ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'main') }}: # only works if you have a main branch
       test: "Create Octopus Release for RC"
     ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'dev') }}: # only works if you have a main branch
       test: "Create Octopus Release for Development"

   steps:

   - script: |
       echo Add other tasks to build, test, and deploy your project.
       echo See https://aka.ms/yaml
     displayName: '$(test)'
   ```
2. You can use Expression to set the displayname in task.

   For example:

   ```yaml
   steps:

   - script: |
       echo Add other tasks to build, test, and deploy your project.
       echo See https://aka.ms/yaml
     ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'main') }}: 
       displayName: 'Create Octopus Release for RC'
     ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'test') }}: 
       displayName: 'Create Octopus Release for Development'
   ```

Result:

[image]