# Use variable in task name

Tags: azure-pipelines

```yaml
variables:
  System.Debug: true
  theDate: $((Get-Date).Day)

jobs:
- job: 'The_job'
  pool:
      vmImage: 'windows-latest'   
  steps:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: 'The task of $[ variables.theDate ]'
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          echo "This is the task. theDate is $(theDate)"
```

PowerShell prints out the date, but the task name comes out as `The task of $[ variables.theDate ]`.
I've tried `{{` instead of `[` but that doesn't work either.

Can this be made to work or is it just impossible?

Comment: Have you tried `$(theDate)`?

Comment: Comes out as `The task of $( theDate )`. This really seems to be impossible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [task displayName set to dynamic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71915488/task-displayname-set-to-dynamic)

Comment: Isn't that just saying to use `$(theDate)`? Which doesn't work.

Comment: Task display names appear to be fixed when the pipeline plan is compiled. So variables explicitly available at compile time will be available, but any dynamic variables created during runtime are not. I would assume `theDate` is not available until runtime and thus can't be used for a task's name.

Comment: Ah, so it is impossible.

Comment: Well, at a *minimum*, you can't use PowerShell commands in YAML variables, so `$((Get-Date).Day)` as a variable will absolutely not work.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
variables:
  currentDay: $[ format('{0:dd}', pipeline.startTime) ]

jobs:
- job: 'PrintDay'
  pool:
      vmImage: 'windows-latest'   
  steps:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: 'The task of $(currentDay)'
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          echo "This is the task. theDate is $(currentDay)"
```

[image]

Comment: So whther it works depends how you get the value of the variable.

Comment: It depends on whether the variable is available at resolvable at compile time or during runtime. Task names are generated at compile time, so if you plan to use a variable in your task name, it must be able to be resolved at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

The display name of a task is fixed when the pipeline plan is compiled. Variables explicitly mentioned in the YAML file are available at compile time, but dynamic variables created during runtime are not.

`theDate` appears to be being assigned a value at runtime - based on the fact its value is `$((Get-Date).Day)` which is macro syntax and only resolved at runtime - and so I would assume is not available at compile time to be used in a task's name.

EDIT: Based on Scott's answer, it is possible to set `theDate` at compile time using a different definition/method.

Comment: FWIW, `Get-Date` is a *PowerShell* command. The original poster needs to be disabused of the notion that you can execute an arbitrary PowerShell command in a YAML pipeline outside of specifically within a script task.